# how much c programming should I know before indulging into sdl programming

Tags: c, graphics, sdl

I have programmed in c and I know about data structures and algorithms, but It has been a while since I programmed in c. I forgot things like how function pointers and some advanced stuff in c work. I want to try graphics programming using sdl. my question is how much of c should I know (for example should I know function pointers) before getting into this. Or in other words will I be stuck if I dont remember a lot?

Answer (score 3):

I think basic knowledge of C should be enough. Look for some SDL tutorials and follow them closely, you will refresh your knowledge of C and at the same time learn how to use SDL. It might go a little slower at first, but you will get into it.

Try for example: [SDL Tutorials](http://www.sdltutorials.com/)
Or: [GPWiki SDL tutorials](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/C:SDL_tutorials)
Or: [Lazy foo](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/index.php)

The first one offers also C tuts. As for functions pointers, you might need them later, when you get to the more advanced stuff. With the basics, you will see everything in tutorial source code and believe me it is easy to understand.

If you like books, try: [Focus on SDL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592000304)
Dont know if there are better ones.

Comment: do you also happen to know a good book on sdl? It is better if it is also used as a reference

Answer (score 1):

I see PeterK posted lots of good stuff, but I figured I'd throw my two cents in as well.  When I started using SDL (3-4 months ago), I had a little experience in Java and no experience in c/c++.  Using LazyFoo's tutorials (http://lazyfoo.net/), I was able to get up to speed very easily.  I would recommend it to anyone who wants to learn SDL.